# The use of DO as adverb of quality

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

I found this sentence in a blog:

`I didn't do tell him anything`

In the sentence above, I see that `do` is the adverb.
Is it *gramatically* correct to write like that where /didn't/, /do/ and the verb /tell/ in one sentence?

Here's one of other examples:
[image]

It says:
.... he really did love ....

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  I would expect to see "I didn't tell him anything".  I don't think "do" belongs in that sentence.

Comment: I also think that `didn't` is an absolute statement and do not require `do` to emphasize it. But, is it grammatically correct? If it is not correct, how the adverb should be used?

Comment: @Herman Nz "Do" is not an adverb, so how can we advise you how it should be used?

Comment: I ever learn (in one of Betty Schrampfer Azar's books) like this: `I do care`  or `I did care`. So, what is `do` in this case? and, how to change it into negative sentence?

Comment: It's almost always a verb: sometimes a 'dummy' auxiliary verb used for emphasis as in "But I _do_ care"; or in questions _Do you care_? or in negatives _I do not care_. In other cases it's a lexical verb, as in _I will do my best_ . It also has a minor use as a noun, as in _What a great do!_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't, in any variety of English that I am aware of.

"Do/does/did" *may* be used in an affirmative sentence before any other verb*, for emphasis (in a negative or interrogative sentence it's obligatory before most verbs) *as long as there isn't another auxiliary*.

In "I didn't do tell him anything" there are two auxiliaries ('didn't' and 'do') so it is not grammatical.

In "he really did love her" there is no other auxiliary besides "did", so it is grammatical.

(* except "be")

Comment: Thanks mr @Fine. In a phrase, say, "an English book". Here, word "English" is a noun which modifies the other word "book". Since "English" modifies "book", "English" has a similar function as an Adjective, right?
What about "DO" in " he really did love her". Could it be called as an Adverb of Quality or as an "specific" auxiliary like you said (for emphasis) ?. Thanks again :p

Comment: What does your closing *except "be"* refer to?

Comment: @HermanNz: No. The important question is, "Is it grammatical?" In other words, "Do native speakers use if that way?". If the answer is 'yes', then we can figure out what the grammar is. Since the answer is 'no', there is no grammar to figure out. "English" is an adjective, and is one of the things (not the only one) which may modify a noun. "Do" is not (so far) an adverb: it is a verb, which changes to "does", "did", "doing", or "done" in suitable contexts. Perhaps at some time in the future "do" will come to function as an adverb, but now it does not in any variety of English that I know.

Comment: @Lawrence: it was meant to be a footnote (marked by the asterisk) but Stackexchange turned the asterisk into a bullet.

Comment: Thanks @ColinFine, your explanation is clear enough. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Mr. Fine's fine response, it is worth noting that "do" is used as an auxiliary verb (either as emphasis in affirmative sentences or in negatives and interrogatives) for all verbs except the verb "be".